# Get short link of a trello board/card on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, trello

I have a Trello app on iPhone, and I want to share the link of a Trello board/card with my friends via whatsapp. But I can't find this anyway in the iPhone app.

Any idea where I can look for it?

Comment: Have you tired the ComputerBrowser version?
Ist there any Link which you can copy?

Comment: @SomeOneWhoNeedsHELP-TY, well... not too sure what is the relevancy of your comment to my question. I am asking about iOS native app which is obviously different from web browser app